# For Loop does not iterate variable

Tags: javascript

EDIT NOTES2:
See working Answer Below.

EDIT NOTES:
I have moved the if statements into the for loop as advised. However it would appear the value in **templateIndex** is still not ticking up.

```
var templateIndex = 0;
var templateCounter;
var templateid;

for (var templateCounter = 0; templateCounter <= 3; templateCounter++) {
    templateIndex++;


    if (templateIndex === 1) {
        var templateid = "1zpKsKi67AZ4SehuOA4XutExO2XhqKcSbMwtR6f4vMoM";
    }
    if (templateIndex === 2) {
        var templateid = "1KRyJo2CkR2YCDZ7YhPeNSU3DRJDy0xbRhoPX_M34XbE";
    }
    if (templateIndex === 3) {
        var templateid = "1e4XAaqCC04w3zWxImalQ5u-ej-_TGJ8RF6y9beTxTls";
    }
    if (templateIndex === 4) {
        var templateid = "1tsM9SUkfq1Bb-lWAHLRKH4F2RUT-5JaJ6qoXIQVrMao";
    }

}
```

Can someone explain to me why the variable **templateIndex** is not ticking up in this case?

When i run this code, **templateid** always stays at the value 0.
To put it another way, when run, templateid only uses the value assigned when the first "if" is true.

The idea here being I want to the ID in the first IF to be used for the first run through. Second run through uses Second Template ID, and so on.

```
var templateIndex = 0 

for(var templateCounter = 0; templateCounter <=3; templateCounter++)
{templateIndex++}

if (templateIndex === 1){
var templateid = "ID of First template to be used.";
}
if (templateIndex === 2){
var templateid = "ID of Second template to be used.";
}
if (templateIndex === 3){
var templateid = "ID of Third template to be used.";
}
if (templateIndex === 4){
var templateid = "ID of Fourth template to be used.";
}
```

Comment: `templateCounter++);` > What's that `;` doing there?

Comment: `{templateIndex++}` > What's that `}` doing there?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use multiple `var` statements to declare the same variable like that.

Comment: What's that `{` and `}` not doing there.

Comment: @Cerbrus
I only want templateCounter to run 4 times.
For each time it runs, templateIndex should tick up by 1.

Keith
I don't understand your question.

Comment: @New_2_Code: Run your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ and see if you can figure out why the `if` conditions aren't working like you expect. It has to do with how you built your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be as follows if you want it to run:

```
var templateIndex = 0;
for(var templateCounter = 0; templateCounter <=3; templateCounter++{
  templateIndex++;
}

if (templateIndex === 1){
  var templateid = "ID of First template to be used.";
}
if (templateIndex === 2){
  var templateid = "ID of Second template to be used.";
}
if (templateIndex === 3){
  var templateid = "ID of Third template to be used.";
}
if (templateIndex === 4){
  var templateid = "ID of Fourth template to be used.";
}
```

However, I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to do, because the result will always be 4 for templateIndex after the code has run.

If you want to step through templateIndex and then execute some code on each step, then here is an example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var templateIndex = 0;
        var templateCounter;
        var templateid;

        for(var templateCounter = 0; templateCounter <=3; templateCounter++){
            templateIndex++;
            if (templateIndex === 1){
                    templateid = "ID of First template to be used.";
                    $('#steps').append('<li>'+templateid+'</li>');
                    /* whatever you want to do here */  
                }
                if (templateIndex === 2){
                    templateid = "ID of Second template to be used.";
                    $('#steps').append('<li>'+templateid+'</li>');  
                    /* whatever you want to do here */  
                }
                if (templateIndex === 3){
                    templateid = "ID of Third template to be used.";
                    $('#steps').append('<li>'+templateid+'</li>');  
                    /* whatever you want to do here */  
                }
                if (templateIndex === 4){
                    templateid = "ID of Fourth template to be used.";
                    $('#steps').append('<li>'+templateid+'</li>');  
                    /* whatever you want to do here */  
                }
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body id="demos">
<h1>Result</h1>
<ul id='steps'></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Please give a bit more information and we can try to be of more help.

Comment: I've got a PDF Mail Merge script that runs over a loop.
Inside that loop I I use the value that is assigned to **templateid**. 
I want to code in the main loop to run 4 times. (Each time with a different Template ID)
Once the loop has run 4 times, it moves onto the next row and starts again.
-
Please note, I am only sharing sample of my code, and I have gotten the above to work fine. Now I just the the ID to change per loop.

Comment: The whole problem is that the `if` statements are outside of the loop. That's all.

Comment: I've put the if statements inside the for loop.
I am still getting the same result. (Namely only the first template ID is used.)

Is there a place I can dump my script so you guys can have a look at the full script?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the template IDs are constant for each loop, you can do it more concisely like this:

```
var templateIds = {"ids":["id1","id2","id3","id4"]}; //Load these from somewhere
var lastRowIndex = 100; //some random value simulating sheet.getLastRow()

//Assuming your row array is zero-indexed
for(rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < lastRowIndex; rowIndex++) {
    console.log("Doing stuff for row index: " + rowIndex);
    for (var templateCounter = 0; templateCounter < templateIds.ids.length; templateCounter++) {
        //An external function isn't necessary here, but I think it sometimes improves readability
        doStuff(templateIds.ids[templateCounter]);
    };
};

function doStuff(templateId)
{
    console.log("\t\tIf I were a real function, I'd be doing stuff with TemplateID: " + templateId);
};
```

Generally speaking, it's best to avoid 'magic numbers' in your code.  What if you decide you want more than 4 template IDs? Or fewer?  In the existing solution you'll need to change your code. If you load them into an array from an external source, you can just iterate through the array without changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of ending my for loop to soon. I terminated it before the mail merge script even had a chance to kick off. Such a foolish/rookie mistake. Yet another case of hitting my head against a wall until it makes sense...

Answer goes to Clinton, however I wanna thanks Cerbrus, as he was correct right from the start.

**Working Code:**

```
My function() {

for(var index = 2; index <= sheet.getLastRow();index++)
{
var templateCounter = 0;
for(templateCounter = 0; templateCounter <= 3; templateCounter++)
{

if (templateCounter === 0){
  var templateid = "1zpKsKi67AZ4SehuOA4XutExO2XhqKcSbMwtR6f4vMoM";
}
if (templateCounter === 1){
  var templateid = "1KRyJo2CkR2YCDZ7YhPeNSU3DRJDy0xbRhoPX_M34XbE";
}
if (templateCounter === 2){
  var templateid = "1e4XAaqCC04w3zWxImalQ5u-ej-_TGJ8RF6y9beTxTls";
}
if (templateCounter === 3){
  var templateid = "1tsM9SUkfq1Bb-lWAHLRKH4F2RUT-5JaJ6qoXIQVrMao";
}

... Mail Merge Script



//End of Template Counter Loop
}
//End of Index loop
}
//End Of My Function
}
```

Comment: One last thing: `var templateid` <-- only ever declare a variable _once_. Use `var templateid;` _before_ the first `if`, then remove `var` inside the 4 `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to get a templateId based on the number of times a function is run.

Example:

```
getTemplateId(); // returns 1st
getTemplateId(); // returns 2nd
getTemplateId(); // returns 3rd
```

Personally, I don't think that's a good structure for your code.  A function should do the same thing consistently and only change if the input changes.

With that said, if you want to continue it this way, you need to have a counter that tracks the number of times a piece of code is run, and then have the piece of code read from that counter.

```
window.templateCounter = 0;
//array of template IDs
window.templates = [
  "1zpKsKi67AZ4SehuOA4XutExO2XhqKcSbMwtR6f4vMoM",
  "1KRyJo2CkR2YCDZ7YhPeNSU3DRJDy0xbRhoPX_M34XbE",
  "1e4XAaqCC04w3zWxImalQ5u-ej-_TGJ8RF6y9beTxTls",
  "1tsM9SUkfq1Bb-lWAHLRKH4F2RUT-5JaJ6qoXIQVrMao"
]
function getTemplate(){

  var thisTemplateID = window.templates[window.templateCounter];
  window.templateCounter++;
  return thisTemplateID;

}

console.log( getTemplate() ); //returns 1zpKsKi67AZ4SehuOA4XutExO2XhqKcSbMwtR6f4vMoM
console.log( getTemplate() ); //returns 1KRyJo2CkR2YCDZ7YhPeNSU3DRJDy0xbRhoPX_M34XbE
console.log( getTemplate() ); //returns 1e4XAaqCC04w3zWxImalQ5u-ej-_TGJ8RF6y9beTxTls
console.log( getTemplate() ); //returns 1tsM9SUkfq1Bb-lWAHLRKH4F2RUT-5JaJ6qoXIQVrMao
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `for` loop is followed by a `;` semicolon so the next block is not the part of your `for` loop and therefore does not get executed.

You can use your for loop like this.

```
for(var templateCounter = 0; templateCounter <=3; templateCounter++){
    templateIndex++;
}
```

Also you are declaring `templateid` inside each if else block but these blocks are not scoped and therefore you can declare it only once and use inside different if else blocks.

Comment: Not the only problem.

Comment: I've removed the ; from the sample code, as well as in my own code. Still having the above issue. As far as I understand you don't have to have an else statement.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp